# Is a blank voided check the same as a fully filled out voided check?

Tags: united-states, check, checking-account

For the last year now, I've collected checks for a company. Procedure is to collect and void the check. For some reason, I'm now asking for a blank voided check.

Isn't a check that's voided just that, voided? Does it legally matter if it's filled out r blank?

Comment: What is it for?

Comment: Arizona, USA. Payment of services.

Comment: How are you being paid with a voided check?

Comment: The company collects a voided check to put the customer's bank account info on file.

Answer (score 5):

Having had several checks collected from me by (typically) utility companies in order to set up automated payments (where the company withdraws funds instead of my initiating a payment each month), I *always* gave them a blank pre-printed *deposit* slip with the bank routing number and personal account imprinted on it in magnetic ink.  *One*
 company demanded a blank voided check in lieu of the deposit slip, the others were quite happy with what I gave them. Since all that is wanted is the numbers, preferably without the digit transpositions, skipped digits or extra inserted digits, or outright substitutions that far too many customers inadvertently (or advertently) make when filling out forms, 
I don't see that it makes much of a difference whether it is a deposit slip or a
check that is collected, nor why having a check filled out and *then* voided instead
of just a blank check marked "VOID" is better. Of course, if they demand an original
check that has been cashed (to prove that the account is active), that may be hard
to do since most (all?) US banks no longer return cashed checks to their customers.